# TweenLite Variable with #ID

Tags: javascript, gsap

I can't understand how it works. Im trying to add a variable in my TweenLite scrollto plugin.

My Variable name is section:

```
var section = 2;

document.getElementById("corner-bottom").onclick = function() {
  if(section < 4){
    section++;
  }
  TweenLite.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:{"#section" + section, offsetY:70}});
}
```

Im getting "Unexpected token +" error.

How can I add variable into my scrollTo id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in your posted code, due to you missing the `y` parameter with your `id` and concatenated `variable`.

Try this:

```
TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:{y:"#section" + section, offsetY:70}});
```

Please see the GSAP ScrollToPlugin Docs for more info:

https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/ScrollToPlugin

:)